# Can't start performance profiler in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My version is **14.0.25431.01 Update 3** *(Windows 7 Pro x64)*.
When I try and run the performance profiler I get the following errors:

> Performance Session File does not exist or is invalid.

When I click on OK I get a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Things I did:

- Choose Release configuration (always)
- Run VS as Admin (always)
- /ResetSettings
- /SafeMode
- Repair VS
- Delete *.psess files
- No reference to diagnostics in *.sln file to delete
- Added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team
  Tools\Performance Tools` to system and user path environment variable
  and rebooted.

I'm running out of options here.....

Comment: I have a similar problem - any progress on this yet? Strangely, I'm running the same (git) project on another machine and it works fine (same version of VS, same config, same OS...). Up-vote hoping to get an answer...!